# Having problems with for loops with Django Tags

Tags: python, html, django, tags

I seem to be having a problem with Django using a for loop. For some reason when I display the variable {{count}} in the loop, it does not seem to print out on the webpage. (It works outside the loop on the same template)

Basically I created a `count` variable which will count all `Destroyed`  items in  `item.itemstatushistory_set.latest`. For some reason it does not seem to work.

```
{%for item in items%}
       {%if item.itemstatushistory_set.latest == "Destroyed" %}
               {{count|add:"1" }}
       {% endif %}
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: Did you check the valus of items passing to templates?

Comment: @Flow yes it is correct. As I said, the variable `count` prints outside this loop. Does not want to print inside.

Answer (score 4):

**item.itemstatushistory_set.latest** will return the latest object from the queryset so you are comparing an object to a string.

Is the unicode representation of the **itemstatushistory** model definitely going to be "Destroyed"?

It might be easier to have a function in itemstatushistory to return whether or not it is destroyed instead of comparing it in the template? Or even better, have a function in the item model to return the latest itemstatushistory object which can have an is_destroyed function?

```
class Item(models.Model):
    status_history = models.ManyToManyField(ItemStatusHistory):
    ...

def get_latest_status(self):
    return self.status_history.all().latest()

class ItemStatusHistory(models.Model):
    destroyed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def is_destroyed(self):
    if self.destroyed:
        return true;
    return false;

{% for item in items %}
    {% if item.get_latest_status.is_destroyed %}
        {{ count|add:"1" }}
    {% end if %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: `item.itemstatushistory_set.latest` is basically a list of statuses. (In, out collected, destroyed, etc). The `latest` part just looks for the latest status. And yes the Unicode representation is definitely going to be "Destroyed as well".

Comment: have you checked if the if statement is ever true? i.e. put some text in there instead of count?

Comment: Even if the unicode representation is "destroyed", the actual object won't equal "destroyed". You'll need to compare against an actual field, or method as pastylegs suggests.

Answer (score 0):

I echo pastylegs comment. You first need to make sure that your if look is being executed. It very well may be the situation where you are never entering the if loop.